# How to initialise a GoRouter in a Flutter app with use of persisted data from SharedPreferences?

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

I am rebuilding an existing app in Flutter. There is an onboarding sequence of screens at its first start that is skipped on the subsequent app launches once the onboarding was finished. Nothing extraordinary.

I am also trying to use a GoRouter for navigation. The idea was that I use the `initialLocation` parameter of its constructor to implement the above requirement like this:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 …
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: GoRouter(
        …
        initialLocation: expectedCurrentPath,
      ),
    …
    );
  }
}
```

That `expectedCurrentPath` is being conditionally assigned one of the two possible paths based on the value of a bool field that I read out of an instance of SharedPreferences. Once the user is past the last screen of onboarding, I write `true` into that field. So, ideally, next time when the app starts, that conditional evaluates into true and that second path is assigned to `expectedCurrentPath`.

However, there is a huge problem I cannot seem to solve. An instance of SharedPreferences can only be obtained in async way. I have to `await` for it to actually read the value. But this `build` method is not async and I cannot seem to easily make it one - it must return a `Widget` and not a `Future<Widget>`. So, in the code above I am not allowed to `await`.

I tried also making the `main()` function `async` and do the `await` step there like this:

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  // this is a global model-like object to work with my items in SharedPreferences; 
  // an instance of SharedPreferences is created inside that async initialize()
  await myState.initialize();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

But that does not work at all: SharedPreferences already expects the app to exist in order for it to access the storage. When initialised at this position it throws exception.

So, overall, the conflict goes like this: in order to initialise the app, I need a resolved initial location for the router; in order to resolve it, I need to obtain an instance of SharedPreferences; in order to obtain that instance, the app must already be initialized.

How is this typically solved in Flutter? I suspect this is a rather common case and popular components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `main` function:

```
void main() async {
  /// IMPORTANT: Call this.
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  /// Use preferences like expected.
  final preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  runApp(...);
}
```

Why?

"The "instance" getter on the ServicesBinding binding mixin is only available once that binding has been initialized.
Typically, this is done by calling "WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()" or "runApp()" (the latter calls the former)."

Comment: Ugh, wow! Worked like magic! Many thanks!